# Google Chrome "loading" page indefinitely

Tags: google-chrome

I have a page - quite complex, lots of resources etc.. but it all loads without problems.

However, Google Chrome shows that little "loading" animation in the tab, and there's the "Waiting for (IP)..." bubble in bottom left of the page.

Everything is loaded, as confirmed by developer tools.

Sometimes, I get this in Console, but not always:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
```

Firefox loads it without problem.

What can be the problem?

(sorry, it's on intranet and I'm not allowed to make it accessible - so just in case you encountered similar issue)

Comment: I'll be very surprised if anyone can answer this. We have nothing to go on?

Comment: Yeah it's not ideal :(  When I download the page for offline viewing and then access that, it works fine, so I can't mirror it that way. Was just thinking maybe someone else has similar problem, because it's very annoying and weird - really everything is 100% loaded.